# Cannot find symbo postgresqlContainer. withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, testcontainers, java-17

I have a configuration file for initializing testcontatainers.

```java
@Slf4j
public class PostgresqlContainerInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

   private static final String POSTGRESQL_IMAGE = "postgres:14-alpine";

    private static final String[] CUSTOM_COMMAND_PARTS = {"-c", "shared_buffers=256MB", "-c", "max_connections=300"};

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
            DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRESQL_IMAGE)
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres")
    ).withDatabaseName("testdb");

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        postgresqlContainer.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));
        postgresqlContainer.setCommand(ArrayUtils.addAll(postgresqlContainer.getCommandParts(), CUSTOM_COMMAND_PARTS));
        postgresqlContainer.start();

        ConnectionFactoryOptions options = PostgreSQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer.getOptions(
                postgresqlContainer
        );

        String r2dbcUrl = String.format("r2dbc:pool:postgresql://%s:%s/%s",
                options.getRequiredValue(HOST),
                options.getRequiredValue(PORT),
                options.getRequiredValue(DATABASE)
        );


        TestPropertyValues testPropertyValues = TestPropertyValues.of(
                "r2dbc.db.url=" + r2dbcUrl,
                "r2dbc.db.username=" + options.getRequiredValue(USER),
                "r2dbc.db.password=" + options.getRequiredValue(PASSWORD),
                "r2dbc.db.port="+ options.getRequiredValue(PORT),
                "r2dbc.db.db-name=" + options.getRequiredValue(DATABASE),
                "r2dbc.db.driver-name=" + options.getRequiredValue(DRIVER),
                "r2dbc.db.host=" + options.getRequiredValue(HOST)
        );

        testPropertyValues.applyTo(applicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
}
```

This line causes an error

```java
  postgresqlContainer.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));
```

> /PostgresqlContainerInitializer.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
> postgresqlContainer.withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log));

- build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

....
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'
.....

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'

    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'

    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:r2dbc'
}
```

[image]

What ideas does anyone have, why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class PostgresqlContainerInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresqlContainerInitializer.class);

    private static final String POSTGRESQL_IMAGE = "postgres:14-alpine";

    private static final String[] CUSTOM_COMMAND_PARTS = {"-c", "shared_buffers=256MB", "-c", "max_connections=300"};

    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
            DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRESQL_IMAGE)
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres")
    ).withDatabaseName("testdb");
```

You only need to declare

```java
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostgresqlContainerInitializer.class);
```